# Netbeans 8.0 Composer with Laravel 5

Tags: php, netbeans, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a PHP project with Netbeans 8.0 using Laravel 5. Since some versions ago Netbeans shows a "Composer Tab" during the creation of the project, but I can't undestand how to do it.

[image: Netbeans Composer]

I suppose that "laravel/laravel" is the correct one, but when I launch the project it shows those errors:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\SC\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\SC\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\SC\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\SC\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found this solution (works on Windows 8.1):

1. Create your NetBeans project
2. Use Composer in Netbeans (see my previous post), search "laravel" and add it
3. Donwload the zip file of Laravel from this link: https://github.com/laravel/laravel
4. Unzip the file in your Netbeans project
5. Everything works fine and you can run your project

Comment: The question is about installing Laravel through NetBeans and without the second point it couldn't be complete.

Comment: what previous post? search "Laravel" where? unfortunately your answer is ambiguous, please consider editing it